# How to create an x64 DynamicAssembly

Tags: c#, 64-bit, reflection.emit

I'm currently porting a project of mine from x86 to x64. It is a plugin and absolutely must run as an x64, since the host does too.

Part of the application creates a dynamic assembly:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(...)
```

And then saves that to the disk. I checked it with `dumpbin /headers`, its in x86!

How can I force the assembly to be x64 from code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is entirely normal, assemblies that contain IL code always are packaged in a DLL that has a 32-bit header.  Same thing you get with Project + Properties, Build tab, Platform Target = Any CPU.

Keep in mind: pure .NET assemblies only contain data, no code.  Whether the JIT compiler translates the IL to 32-bit or to 64-bit code is determined by the bitness of the startup EXE.

Comment: Problem is, the host won't run the plugins. Even worse: I get no error message either. That is why I'm suspecting the host is having difficulties dynamically loading the assembly. The host is a native application, offering .NET extensibility features.

Comment: Excuse me. Just started PC today and everything works. Thanks for shedding some light on the issue!